# How do I query Firestore all documents today date?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to generate report at a fixed schedule. But I am having a problem where I cannot retrieve the date for today onwards until the current time where the function will run.

```
exports.generateReport = functions.pubsub.schedule('36 15 * * *').onRun(async (context) => {
    console.log(context);
    const currentTime = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();

    const shopSnapshot = await db.collection("shops").get();
    let shopDoc = shopSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

    const promises = [];
    let transactionList = [];
    let reportList = [];

    let i = 0;

    console.log(shopDoc);

    shopDoc = shopDoc.filter(shop => !!shop.key);
    console.log(shopDoc);

    for(var j=0; j<shopDoc.length; j++){
        console.log("Enter shop ID:"+shopDoc[j].key);
        promises.push(db.collection("shops").doc(shopDoc[j].key).collection("transactions").get());
    }  

    const snapshotArrays = await Promise.all(promises);

    snapshotArrays.forEach(snapArray => {
        snapArray.forEach(snap => {
            //console.log(snap.data());
            transactionList.push({data: snap.data(), key: shopDoc[i].key});
        })
        i++;
    }); 

    for(var k=0; k<shopDoc.length; k++){
        let amount = 0;
        for (var l=0; l<transactionList.length; l++){
            if(shopDoc[k].key === transactionList[l].key){
                console.log("get date");

                if (transactionList[l].data.createAt < currentTime){
                    amount += transactionList[l].data.amount;
                    console.log(amount);
                }
            }
        }
        reportList.push({amount: amount, key: shopDoc[k].key});
    }

    console.log(reportList);
    console.log(transactionList);

});
```

[image: This is Firestore document and collection images]

I tried using `new Date()` also compared with a string of date exactly the same as Firestore Timestamp format but still all transaction appear before the time or no transaction is included at this time.

Comment: For testing purpose, that is why I put ```functions.pubsub.schedule('36 15 * * *')```. I would like to check whether all transaction documents createAt is today date. Then I will only take all the transaction documents that is today date

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer (I had deleted my comment meanwhile... because I saw that you were doing `transactionList[l].data.createAt < currentTime`)

Comment: If I correctly understand your business need you somehow want to run the Cloud Function tomorrow at 00:01 and select all the transactions of today, in such a way you can generate a report with all the transaction of the previous day. Is that right?

Comment: Ya I want to get the from today date until current time

Comment: Yup that is correct

Comment: Sorry I am a bit puzzled...  When you say "get from today date until current time" do you mean the current time will be tomorrow at 00:01 (as detailed in my comment)? To answer your question I need to exactly know what you want to achieve. The problem is that by using "until current time" in your explanations it makes things not 100% clear, if I may.

Comment: Current time mean current time of the schedule run as the report will be generated at 2 hours from 00:01. The report function is to generate total amount from 00:01 to current time. So upon calling this function, this function will calculate all transaction that is done today until current time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204120/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-raynne).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I correctly understand that you want to generate a daily report for all the transactions that occurred yesterday by running a schedule Cloud Function today at 00:05 for example, here is a possible approach using the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const moment = require('moment');

admin.initializeApp();


exports.generateReport = functions.pubsub.schedule('05 00 * * *').onRun(async (context) => {

    let m1 = moment();
    let m2 = moment();
    m1.add(-1, 'days');
    m2.add(-1, 'days');
    m1.startOf('day');
    m2.endOf('day');


    const shopSnapshot = await db.collection("shops").get();
    let shopDoc = shopSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

    const promises = [];
    let transactionList = [];
    let reportList = [];

    let i = 0;

    shopDoc = shopDoc.filter(shop => !!shop.key);
    console.log(shopDoc);

    for(var j=0; j<shopDoc.length; j++){
        console.log("Enter shop ID:"+shopDoc[j].key);
        promises.push(
          db.collection("shops")
            .doc(shopDoc[j].key)
            .collection("transactions")
            .orderBy("createAt")
            .where("createAt", ">", m1.toDate())
            .where("createAt", "<=", m2.toDate())
            .get()
       );
    }  

    const snapshotArrays = await Promise.all(promises);

    snapshotArrays.forEach(snapArray => {
        snapArray.forEach(snap => {
            //console.log(snap.data());
            transactionList.push({data: snap.data(), key: shopDoc[i].key});
        })
        i++;
    }); 

    for(var k=0; k<shopDoc.length; k++){
        let amount = 0;
        for (var l=0; l<transactionList.length; l++){
            if(shopDoc[k].key === transactionList[l].key){
                 amount += transactionList[l].data.amount;
            }
        }
        reportList.push({amount: amount, key: shopDoc[k].key});
    }

    //.....

});
```

So, what do we do in this code?
First we create two moment objects and we set their date to yesterday. Then, with [`startOf()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) and [`endOf()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) we adjust the time of the first one to yesterday at 12:00:00.000 am (i.e. 00:00:00, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock)) and the second one to yesterday at 11:59:59.999 pm (i.e. 23:59:59).

With these two dates, for each transactions collection, we adapt the [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) as follows, calling the `toDate()` method:

```
db.collection("shops")
                .doc(shopDoc[j].key)
                .collection("transactions")
                .orderBy("createAt")
                .where("createAt", ">", m1.toDate())
                .where("createAt", "<=", m2.toDate())
                .get();
```

And that's it. The big advantage here, is that the filtering is done in the Firestore database (in the back-end), not in the front-end as you did in your question (`if (transactionList[l].data.createAt < currentTime){...}`)

Comment: Not sure why when I used ```orderByChild``` it appears error of it is not a function. But it works fine when I used ```orderBy```. Thanks for your detailed explanation

Comment: Glad I could help you! Yes there was a typo with orderBy since I adapted one of my code made for the Realtime Database. Good that you caught it!